# App engine + java + keberos Token

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I have developed a google app engine application which supports integrated windows authentication using JAAS.

For enabling integrated authentication on Mozilla firefox i have made following configuration

```
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris = domain of the trusted uri
network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn = false
network.negotiate-auth.allow-proxies = true
network.negotiate-auth.using-native-gsslib = true.
```

My application doesnt support ntlm so havent made any configuration related to that.

Everything works fine locally. I mean the browser is able to get kerberos service token and send it to my application.

But when I deployed in google app engine. Then browser unable to send kerberos token. I always got NTLM token.

Below is the flow
1. I hit the trusted url from mozilla browser from local network.
2. My application  challenges browser for service token with 401 Negotiate challenge
3. Browser tries to get service token.
4. I observed that it sends NTLM token.

I want to know why the browser is sending NTLM token to app engine and how should I handle such scenario ?

Comment: Just trace Kerberos protocol on the client side ... does it send a TGS-REQ to KDC? Does it get a TGS-RSP?

Comment: Thanks Bernhard Thalmayr.